# How to delete mtu table?

Tags: networking

I am trying to reset mtu table on my linux environment.
I am trying the following:

```
ip route flush cache
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestoins?
Thanks.

Comment: fwiw `ip route flush cache` is a NO-OP: IPv4 cache has been [removed in kernel 3.6](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/netdev/net-next.git/commit/?id=5e9965c15ba88319500284e590733f4a4629a288 "Merge branch 'kill_rtcache'") (2012). If you read documentation written before 2012 (or even a bit after) using `ip route ... cache` on IPv4, chances are the informations are misleading (afaik there's still an IPv6 cache)

Comment: worth a read (written in 2015): https://blog.cloudflare.com/path-mtu-discovery-in-practice/

Answer (score -1):

MTU is Maximum Transfert Unit. It's not a table, it's a parameter to tell what is the maximum packet size to be transferred out of an interface. It can't be flushed.

What do you want to do ? If you want to flush your routing table, you have to call `ip route flush` for each routing rules as mentionned in the manpage (`man 8 ip-route`)

```
        ip route flush
          flush routing tables
          this command flushes routes selected by some criteria.

          The arguments have the same syntax and semantics as the arguments of ip route show, but routing tables are not listed but purged. The only difference is the default action:
          show dumps all the IP main routing table but flush prints the helper page.

          With the -statistics option, the command becomes verbose. It prints out the number of deleted routes and the number of rounds made to flush the routing table. If the option
          is given twice, ip route flush also dumps all the deleted routes in the format described in the previous subsection.
```

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading. Linux keeps a cache of discovered path MTU, and that table overrides the value set on the interface.